# CXF Wsdl2Java Best Practice

Tags: cxf, wsdl2java

I'm currently using cxf 2.4.0 and my code is a caller to a webservice.  I was able to generate the client side java files using the cxf plugin in Maven.  My question is what is the best practice for the generated files?  Should I compile the generated files and package the generated class files into a single jar file or should I include all of the generated java files in the build path?

Answer (score 1):

I get CXF to generate the code under *target*, it picks *target/generated-sources/cxf* by default, which is good by me. (If you're using xjc for handling a schema, it uses a similar scheme. Maven is great for conventions!)

What I sometimes do is put the generated code in its own maven module, which can sometimes simplify things; Eclipse is not entirely happy with generated source code (it doesn't like the fact that cleaning rips the source code out from under it's feet) so corralling that out of sight makes things much simpler. After all, it's just a library that happens to be generated from a WSDL document…

Comment: NB: This works fine whether you put the WSDL document in the project or download it from an external source during compilation; I mostly prefer the former as that cuts the number of things that can go wrong (especially with XSD dependencies of your WSDL dependencies, which can sometimes end up at a server that doesn't like automated clients).

Comment: Why target and not main? I'm new to Java development and I can't find the reason why target is the default setting.

Answer (score 0):

For generated code, I normally create a "generated" folder under "main" (main/src/java - main/generated/java) and I have CXF to generate the classes there. Then I just add the "generated" folder to the compiler source path.

Comment: Thanks!  What is the reason not to jar the generated class files?  Is it due to dependency management issue on your webservice technology?  That the generated files are lock down to a specific version of CXF and it is hard to upgrade and maintain

Comment: No, it's just a matter of preference. If your wsdl change often, you have to regenerate the sources and recreate the jar. If your wsdl is "static" you can very well create a jar out of your generated code. I don't think there is really a best practice here.

Answer (score 0):

Create a build task (ant/maven) that generates the code and packages the compiled code into a jar file.  When the wsdl changes, you only have to re-run the build task.

If you choose to generate the source, use the [Generated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/Generated.html) annotation.  Most wsdl generation tools have this option.